# How to customize inputs in Iterate Feature Class - ModelBuilder 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, feature-class, file-geodatabase

I am using the Iterate Feature Class tool in ModelBuilder to iterate through feature classes within a Geodatabase. I would like to add the capability to custom select which feature classes within a single GDB to iterate through. This desired capability is very similar to the "Input Datasets" step of Merge (Data Managment).

[image]

The Iterate Feature Class tool only provides you with 3 ways to filter:

-Feature Type (line, polygon, etc)
-Wildcard
-Recursive

The ability to custom select which feature classes to iterate does not exist, can someone please help me figure out how to customize the input? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create the interface you are asking for with the iterator.  If you want the interface as in the merge tool you need to add to your model a variable of type FeatureClass and tick on MultiValue and expose it as a parameter. This will give your the required selection control.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do the feature classes you want to iterate through have in common with each other/why do you need to select just those? (might help me give a better answer).  Two suggestions:

1. Rename the feature classes you would like to iterate through so that the wildcard parameter can be used in the tool. Example, prefix each feature class name with a common identifier that is unique to just those names and then use the wildcard symbol (*)
2. Export the desired feature classes to a new geodatabase so you can iterate through the entire folder without needing to limit the selection with a wildcard.
3. Based on the great answer by @Hornbydd, after you add the multivalue feature class variable as mentioned, insert the 'Iterate Multivalue' command to proceed with your model.